# 'Logging' does not exist in the namespace Microsoft.Extensions

Tags: c#, .net-core

So I have the following line at line 1 of the file.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
```

On building it throws

```
CS0234 C# The type or namespace name 'Logging' does not exist in the namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Have tried searching around but was unable to find any solution or reason. The project is set to build in  `.net core 2.0`, have downloaded and installed `.NET Core 2.0 SDK (v2.1.202)`, but the error remains.

Have tried changing the build version to `2.1`, `3.0` didn't help either.

Comment: You have to install the NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.extensions.logging/

Comment: *All Microsoft.Extensions.* libraries are available as NuGet packages that have to be added to a project. Web projects, or projects using the Generic host add some of those packages automatically (Logging, Configuration, Dependency Injection etc).

Comment: Adding the package manually worked. But for some reasons my team mates didn't have to do that. Maybe I'm missing some installation?

Comment: @hackerl33t Once you install a NuGet package on a Project, it will insert something like `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.1.10" />` to the .csproj file. After this, if you give your code to your teammates they will not need to install anything, because it was already installed by you. And the package will be downloaded automatically (because the package was found in .csproj file).

Comment: @rytisk maybe a stupid question here, but how are these packages handled on the deployment side? will the neccessairy assemblies automatically get included in the Build? will it be covered in the runtime? I don't have much practical experience with .Net :-/

Answer (score 2):

Using .Net 6.0, I was able to replicate:

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Logging' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Extensions' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

by refering to `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;` as you did:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
```

*and* installing any extensions package, except the logging, from the command line:

`$ dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives`

I can get rid of your error by adding the package `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`:

`$ dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`